# Is there a way to characterize how close a set is to continuity?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Consider the following images which are subsets of the interval $[0, 1]$: $Im \ f = [0, 0.5]\cup[0.9,1]$, $Im \ g = \{0.1, 0.4, 0.6, 0.65\}$, $h$ is non-surjective with codomain $[0.4, 0.5]$ and has image of a countably infinite sequence converging to 0.5, $Im \ j$ is the irrational numbers on the interval, $Im \ k$ is the algebraic reals, etc.

I'm wondering whether there exists any interesting or noteworthy way to characterize the degree to which these functions (or any function that does a certain degree of filling) are filling up the interval $[0, 1]$, i.e., how close their image is to continuity, which could help us classify or relate them to one another. I was hoping to find something else than cardinality, since it doesn't tend to give much else than either aleph null or aleph one. Would anyone have suggestions? (Of course, the notion of 'filling up' is very vague, so any leads for further investigation to clarify such a characterization are very appreciated! )

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is the measure of a  set.  Eg.  
$\mu(Im \ f) = \mu([0, 0.5]\cup[0.9,1]) = (1-0.9) + (0.5 - 0) = 0.6$
We have $1$-dimensional measure is the "length" of a set, $2$-dimensional is the "area" of a set, $0$-dimensional is the cardinality.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)
.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_measure

Comment: Given any topological space $X,$ $X$ is the image of a continuous function, namely the identity $X\to X.$

Comment: @user3257842 thanks a lot for the reference! I'll look up those terms